# Why can't I modify a vector that I pass by reference?

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, pass-by-reference

This is the first time I'm trying to use pass by reference with vectors. I thought I did it correctly, but I get `error: no viable overloaded '='` on the line that tries to assign `a[0] = 5`

```
void BubbleSort(vector<int> *a) {
    int n = a->size(), numberOfSwaps = 0;   
    if (n > 0)
        a[0]= 5;
}


int main(){
    // input size and array
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for(int a_i = 0;a_i < n;a_i++){
       cin >> a[a_i];
    }
    // sort
    BubbleSort(&a);
    // print
    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' '; 

    return 0;
}
```

edit:

So now that I've been informed that I'm actually passing by pointer, my question is, should I be passing vectors by reference or by pointer, or does it not matter?

Comment: In `BubbleSort` the type of your parameter `a` is `vector<int>*`, change it to `vector<int>&` or dereference the pointer before using `operator[]` as follows: `(*a)[0] = 5;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector<int> *` is not a reference. `vector<int> *` is a pointer.

Either change the function to take a reference as a parameter, or use (*a)[0]=5.

However, after you fix this program so that it compiles, when you run it, it will crash immediately as a result of undefined behavior due to accessing non-existent contents of the vector. You have other, multiple bugs to fix, in this code.

Comment: is passing a vector by reference or by pointer the preferred way? Does it not matter, or does it depend on the usage somehow?

Comment: Depends on the usage. Sometimes it's better to pass by a pointer, sometimes by a reference. Sometimes it's better to ride a bicycle, when going somewhere, and sometimes it's better to ride the bus.

Comment: @Jake : Typical case where you'd need a pointer over a reference is the fact you can pass a nullptr but you cannot pass a null reference.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing by reference, you're passing a pointer. You need to dereference the pointer before you can access operator [].

`(*a)[0] = 5;`